# Unable to fetch object by id in JDOQL

Tags: jdo, hbase, jdoql

I am pretty naive to hbase and JDO. I was trying to use

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(MyClass.class, "id == " + taskId);
List<MyClass> taskList = (List<MyClass>)q.execute();
```

But to my disappointment the list I am receiving is blank. although the taskId in the argument is already present.

Any kind of help would highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fetching an object by id then would make way more sense to call

```
pm.getObjectById(...)
```

and if using a query, it would be normal to look at the log

Answer (score 0):

try

taskList = (List) pm.detachCopy(taskList);

after your code